# Realm of the mad god closed realm question

Tags: realm-of-the-mad-god

I know that you can exit a closed realm by typing in the chatbox: `/tutorial` and then finish the tutorial and enter the realm again.
But what happens if you're in the tutorial and everyone else teleports to Oryx's castle and you enter the realm portal again through the tutorial?

Comment: Try it out and see for yourself :) I'd think you will be transported back to the hub but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

> But if you're in the tutorial and everyone else teleports to oyrx's castle and you enter the realm portal again through the tutorial what happens?

You enter the realm normally, but the realm will be lonely as most people are in the castle. The point here is that call to Oyrx's castle is instantaneous, if you miss it for some reason, you have to wait for the next one - and there is nothing you can do to enter the castle on your own.

See related question: [Can I get back into Oryx's chamber if I died during the fight?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/59909/can-i-get-back-into-oryxs-chamber-if-i-died-during-the-fight)

When you die or leave the castle, you can't re-enter the instance. You can only wait for the next one.

Answer (score -1):

You get sent to another realm, and anyways with the tutorial thing, i don't think it works 100% of the time